# iOS automation with appium on Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, eclipse, appium-ios

I am new into Appium iOS, Can someone give me the step by step installation process for Appium test on Mac OS using simulator.

Note - I have installed Xcode, and have source file of app. Now which setting is required and which capabilities I need to add in code in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

First of all You need to install appium desktop from here

https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.1.0-beta.2

Then, start the appium server by clicking on "Start Server" button

Next, you have to add the following desired capabilities in you code

```
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "10.3");
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone Simulator");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
        cap.setCapability("bundleId", bundleId);

    cap.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
        return new AppiumDriver("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub", cap);
```

Comment: These capabilities are for Android, I am looking for iOS.

Comment: Thanks @Prateeksha. I am able to run the code now. But when I run the code, App starts and closes instantly. Could anyone help ?

Comment: Try to open the app manually, which is installed on the simulator. Might be the case that app is not supported 
PS : simulator require builds specifically created for simulators

Comment: please share you code then, may be we could find something there